# Can I integrate an iOS calendar in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calendar

At the moment I am creating an iOS app with Swift. 
In the app I want among others one of my shared iCloud calendars to be displayed. 
It would be best if this iOS calendar is just displayed within the app. 
An important feature is that if I add an event in my shared calendar it should of course also be added to the app.
An amazing but optional feature would be: 
My AppleID of course can edit the calendar. If the app would recognise that I am using a device with an AppleID that is allowed to edit the calendar so that I would be able to edit the calendar.

To sum it up: it would be best if in my app the iOS calendar is just embedded.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you looking for https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit

EventKit is the way to read from the calendar.

After that, you can choose how to display the events that you get. The easiest way for me was in a UITableView.

Comment: Yes I know about EventKit. But is there a way to copy the interface or integrate the interface and design of the iOS calendar?

Comment: Why you need this? But in general yes you can check for different libraries which will give you the UI part of the calendar and if you using EventKit you can create copy of the iOS calendar.

Comment: First of all thank you very much. 
In my app my employees should see important meetings. 
I have to separate it from the common iOS calendar to ensure that business and private life are separated.
In addition I really like the idea of having everything collected at the same place. 
Do you maybe even know a manual how to embed the iOS calendar in an app?

Comment: There is no way to embed  iOS calendar in an app. What you can do is to creat with new calendar instance for your employees. And they can added on there phones. Or as I mentioned to create simple app with eventKit.